# Julia: Drawing of a table besides a plot

Tags: matplotlib, julia, gadfly, plots.jl

I have the following requirement and wondering if I could solve it with Julia: draw a SVG plot with up to 4 curves on it. Each curve has to be constructed out of 6 data points.
The plot title and the legend should be positioned on the top right corner outside of the plot area.

So far so easy, I'm pretty certain it's solvable with one of the great Julia metapackages. But this one drives me crazy:
In the bottom right corner outside of the plot area a table should be drawn. It should contain the values of 6 data points of each curve.

Example:

```
|     pressure   |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |   6  |
|----------------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|------|
| colored line 1 | 3.8 | 3.9 | 4.1 | 5.0 | 9.1 | 10.0 |
| colored line 2 | 4.0 | 4.1 | 5.0 | 7.1 | 8.0 | 11.0 |
|      gal/min   |     |     |     |     |     |      |
```

The plot and the data table should be placed both inside the SVG.
After studying the documentation for hours I'm still clueless how to draw this table. Is this even possible with a plotting library?

Comment: I'd probably use Weave.jl - use a plotting library to do the plot, then use Weave to present it with a table.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response,

it seeams that Weave.jl don't support SVG as export format. Unfortunately the plot and the data table should be placed both inside the SVG. I've forgot to mention it in my question.

Comment: Then possibly Compose.jl would be a possibility, but I haven't worked with that in years.

Comment: It looks promising, but the documentation is quite sparse. So I eventually plotted the graphs with gnuplot and drew the data table by manipulating the SVG directly with a script.